# Pass Data attribute to jquery set value to option

Tags: jquery, laravel

How would you set the value in the option value with the data-attribute for example

```
data-role_id="{{ $member->role_id }} "
```

And when I click on the modal it shoule display

My code like this :

```
$('select#role_id').val($(this).data('role_id'));
```

But it doesn't display

Comment: So you want the options to have that kind of `data-role` ?

Comment: Yes. In my option value if the data is 3 then the corresponding value which is 3 for example this time it must be changed to that value of 3.

Comment: better you can explain the scenario in fiddle/snippet

Comment: When I cick on that button the modal will be shown . The form will be displayed with the option value of that data-attribute. Sorry for the bad english. For example : 

my data-role_id = 3.. Then the corresponding value in the option which is 3 should be automatically selected.

Answer (score 0):

You'll just need to find the `option` with the same `data-attribute` and set its `selected` property. See working codes below:

```js
$(function (){
   var role = $("#role_id");
       
   console.log("Before: selected role_id = "+role.val());
   
   $("#test_me").click(function () {
       role.children('option[data-role_id="'+$(this).data("role_id")+'"]')
           .attr("selected", "selected");
           
       $("#myModal").modal('show');
       console.log("After: selected role_id = "+role.val())
   })
   
   
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<a href="#" class="btn btn-info" id="test_me" data-role_id="2">Test me!</a>




<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <select id="role_id">
          <option data-role_id="1">1</option>
          <option data-role_id="2">2</option>
          <option data-role_id="3" selected>3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` keyword will be used when you trigger some action on the DOM.So try the below.

```js
$(function(){
$('select#role_id').val($('select#role_id').data('role_id'));

//or

$('select#role_id').on('change',function(){
 $('select#role_id').val($(this).data('role_id'));
})


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Role Id:<select data-role_id='3' name='role_id' id='role_id'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option></select>
```

Comment: Did you check this @d3cypher